# Spring Batch: Setting up a project in Netbeans

Tags: spring, spring-batch, netbeans-8

I'm totally new to Spring and Spring Batch.

My aim is to set up a Spring Batch project in Netbeans 8.0.1.
I've looked through the Spring Batch documentation (both official and unofficial) but to no avail. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start is the Spring.io Guides.  The one for creating a Spring Batch project is the best place to start with Spring Batch.  You can find it here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/